# Rotate an image without rotating element dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rotation

I want to create an effect that when I click on an image element, it will rotate the content inside it but not the element's width and height(My img is 400x300). I want the element dimensions stay but the image rotate. Compressing the height or the width of the image based on the position is fine with me, as long as it does not rotate the element itself.

I have tried jQueryRotate but it seems it's only rotating the element, not the image inside it.

Is there any plugin or way for me to rotate the image without rotating the element itself?

**EDIT:**

My code:

```
$('#rotate-btn').click(function (e) {
    value += 90;
    if (value == 90) {
        var img = document.getElementById('image_canv');
        var width = img.clientWidth;
        var height = img.clientHeight;
        $('#image_canv').height(height);
        $('#image_canv').width(width); {
            animateTo: value
        }
    }
    $('#image_canv').rotate(value);

});
});
```

It does rotate the image, but the position of the element moves, so it's not working out.

Comment: Can you post your code so far and a live demo to reproduce the problem?

Comment: You can see an example of how to rotate here:  http://jsfiddle.net/hQHhf/2/ You actually do not even need jQuery UI for this to work, but I just ticked it from the start just in case, but if you remove it you'll see it works perfectly fine with just the jQuery library.

Comment: Why not give the contents their own div? If in doubt, create an extra couple hundred wrappers.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code also. Right after `$('#image_canv').width(width);` you have an open bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'm assuming that you have a global variable defined as `value`

You can use the following code to rotate by 90 degree increments if that is what you want:

```
var value = 0;
$('#rotate-btn').click(function (e) {
    var element = $("#image_canv");
    var startDegree = value;
    var endDegree = value + 90;
    value += 90;

    $({ i:startDegree }).animate({ i: endDegree }, {
         step: function(now,fx) {
               element.css({transform : 'rotate('+ now + 'deg)' }); 
         },
         duration: 1000
    });
});
```

And here is an example of it working:  http://jsfiddle.net/hQHhf/4/

If you need to rotate by some other increment, than the code will need to be changed slightly to fit those needs.  But basically, your `value` variable should always end up being the same as `endDegree` so that the next rotation will start at the proper place for the image.

Here's an example of how to use it if you are wanting to do varying degrees of rotation, both positive and/or negative (For this, I changed id of rotate-btn to a class instead, and gave it its own function for rotating on any degrees):

```
var value = 0;
$('.rotate-btn').click(function (e) {
    doRotate($(this).val(), 1000);
});

function doRotate(degrees, delay) {
    var element = $("#image_canv");
    var startDegree = value;
    var endDegree = value + parseInt(degrees);
    value = value + parseInt(degrees);

    $({ i:startDegree }).animate({ i: endDegree }, {
        step: function(now,fx) {
            element.css({transform : 'rotate('+ now + 'deg)' });
        },
        duration: delay
    }); 
}
```

And here is an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/hQHhf/6/

Also made some minor edits to the HTML as well, like using `<button>` instead of `<input>` to send a proper value to the `doRotate` function and some other minor edits.

Hope this helps you get the jist of it and apply it for your needs.  Also, because you are setting a width of 400, and a height of 300 on the images, while chrome does not seem effected by this, but some other browsers like firefox will be.  For example, as the image rotates, the size rotates with it, this is because you don't have an equal size on both width and height of your image, so it won't look as tho its rotating naturally in all browsers.  If you give both, width and height, the same size you won't have this problem.

Comment: When using jQuery, vendor prefixes are automatically added, so you actually do not need to use vendor prefixes when declaring the transform property. Also, `-o-` and `-moz-` prefixes for transform simply do not exist http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Comment: Awww, thanks for that bit of info, but this only works if you use `transform` without the quotes correct?

Comment: @Terry - Yes, it is confirmed, you have to use `transform` without the quotes in order for it to be crossbrowser, will update answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i take image with id `myimg` wrap it in div and then rotate it.

http://jsfiddle.net/D5Sz8/

Be carefull all styles applied to image maybe needed to apply on div if you dont want them to rotate along the image.

```
jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
    $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
};


var i= $('img'), d= document.createElement('div'), rotation=0;
d.id='myimg'; i[0].id='';
i.wrap(d);
$('#myimg').css({'display':'inline-block', 'overflow':'hidden'});
ani();

function ani (){
    i.rotate(++rotation);
    requestAnimationFrame(ani);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this javascript code so you can rotate your image easily. But you have only to change the image destination.

```
var looper;
var degrees = 0;
function rotateAnimation(el,speed){

var elem = document.getElementById(el);

if(navigator.userAgent.match("Chrome")){
    elem.style.WebkitTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";

} else if(navigator.userAgent.match("Firefox")){
    elem.style.MozTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";

} else if(navigator.userAgent.match("MSIE")){
    elem.style.msTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";

} else if(navigator.userAgent.match("Opera")){
    elem.style.OTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
} else {
    elem.style.transform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
}
looper = setTimeout('rotateAnimation(\''+el+'\','+speed+')',speed);
degrees++;
if(degrees > 359){
    degrees = 1;
}
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
}
```

And now use the HTML code for the image:

```
<img id="exe" style='position:absolute;left:450px;height:300px;' src="images/example.png"   alt="exe">
```

And it's about to finish just add another script tag:

```
rotateAnimation("exe",30);
```

This function above will move the image 30deg you can change it to 40,50... and the "exe" is the id of the image.